# Angular webpack external scripts bundle too large

Tags: angular, webpack

I have these external scripts  that are a part of webpack build:

```
jquery.min.js
jquery.easypiechart.min.js",
jquery-slimscroll\\jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
tether.min.js",
bootstrap.min.js",
handsontable.full.min.js",
chroma.min.js",
plotly.min.js
```

right now these are being bundled via the ScriptsWebpackPlugin (part of angular cli plugins).

The issue is that the bundle gets to over 3MB large!

I Need suggestions as to how to manage this!

TIA

Comment: is it possible to use cdn for jquery and others libarary  ?

Comment: figured it out.. plotly was over 2mb large !